# New ATV remote, how do you select things?

Tags: appletv

I'm looking at the 4K ATVs, and I see you can get the ones with the older model black remote for ~$50 less. I have one of these for my non-4k TV and quite like it.

That said, the separate power button is kinda handy, and as I rarely use the siri function, having that moved out of the way seems handy. (can you trigger it by mistake picking it up?)

How does the new remote work for selecting and such? It seems to have a wheel rather than a touch pad? Anyone have one that might comment?

Answer (score 1):

User guide is online if the included quick start docs don’t help you or aren’t around when you arrive at the kit.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/tv/charge-the-siri-remote-atvb7d4de50d/tvos

Once you’re sure which generation remote you have from the photos above, here are navigation and selection details.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/tv/navigate-apple-tv-atvbe55a4b4e/tvos

[image]

Comment: So it appears to be both a touch pad and clicker. Interesting.

Comment: I like it a lot better than the darker and thinner / wider one, but both work very well for me.